# C# Menu strip causing forms to crash when button clicked

Tags: c#, menustrip

when I click a button on my menu strip when the system runs sometimes it works fine however, sometimes it throws an error and crashes. The error states '*Parameter not valid*'. I am new to programming and not sure on what this means.

The code I used for the `menu strip button` was

```
private void btnViewChildren_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form myNextScreen = new frmViewChildren();
    myNextScreen.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

What could I be doing wrong? And can someone explain why it works sometimes and doesnt work other times?

Comment: What line throws the error when you debug into it? Is it directly from this event? Is something in the `frmViewChildren` constructor causing the error? You say "sometimes", is there any indication of what is different between successful and unsuccessful attempts?

Comment: Agreed...without further information, our best guess is something  going wrong in frmViewChildren.  What does that form do?...